# Agregar icon a button creado con js

Tags: javascript, jquery, icons

Estoy creando un `button` con `js`, pero necesito que ne vez del texto sea un `icon`,esta es mi linea:

```
row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + '<button  class="btn btn-danger" onclick=\"estado(\'' + data[i].ID + '\')\">Baja</button>'
```

estoy agregando un icon de esta manera:

```
row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + '<button  class="btn btn-danger" onclick=\"estado(\'' + data[i].ID + '\')\"><i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></button>'
```

pero no funciona y el boton se hace de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Ya casi está cerca. Auque no probé este código, puede que funcione, si se agrega el atributo del icono en el mismo botón:

```
row += '<td style="padding:2px;">' + '<button  class="btn btn-danger fas fa-arrow-down" onclick=\"estado(\'' + data[i].ID + '\')\"></button>'
```